# Loading non-standard fonts and displaying them in a QTextDocument

Tags: c++, html, css, qt, fonts

I believe that the problem is solely with QTextDocument's management of non-standard fonts. Nonetheless I will give an overview of what I am doing, in case I have overlooked something in the rest of the code.

I am attempting to print a mixture of rich text (text formatted with qt-supported html tags) and images. The output can be either a PDF, or a physical print-out.

I'm using QImage and QTextDocument to create the images and text, and then QPainter and QPrinter to actually print out the result in a coherent PDF, xps or print-out. The application runs under Windows 7/8.

I need to change the font to non-standard fonts; in my case, Myriad Pro Light and Myriad Pro Semibold. These fonts are not present on windows by default, so I need to install them for the machine or for the application first.

The code, stripped of most irrelevant parts, looks something like:

```
void MyClass::print(QPrinter* printer, MyPrintingSettings settings, QString myRichText)
{
    // load my fancy font
    QString fontPath = "MyriadPro-Light.otf";
    if(!QFile(fontPath).exists() ||
      (QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(fontPath) == -1))
    {
         //this does not happen.
         qDebug() << "could not load font " << fontPath << " :-(\n";
         return;
    }

    // Set the painter and printer for accurate printing of both text
    // and images, with correct re-scaling, regardless of user-selected
    // printer properties.
    printer->pageRect().moveTo(0,0);        
    QPainter m_painter(printer);
    setWindowSize(settings);
    setPrintedRectangle(settings);

    //set the default font for the painter.
    QFont font;
    font.setFamily("Myriad Pro Light");
    font.setPointSize(settings.defaultFontSize);
    m_painter.setFont(font);

    //Create a document for printing. 
    QTextDocument document;
    document.documentLayout()->setPaintDevice(printer);
    document.setDefaultFont(font);
    document.setDocumentMargin(0.0);

    // I believe this is where the font fails to be correctly used.
    document.setHtml(myRichText);

    //drawing/printing.
    document.drawContents(&m_painter);
    m_painter.end();
}
```

The observed output depends on the exact rich text string:

- For a string like: `QString myRichText = "my text"`, the default font is correctly used. This is not a satisfying solution as I need to change the font within rich text strings.
- For a string like: `QString myRichText = "<span style="font-family:Myriad Pro Light;">my text</span>`,the font is not correctly used (tahoma is used instead).
- Installing the font "manually" on the machine does not change anything.
- **Bonus question:** I don't know if this is a related issue. If I install "Myriad Pro Semibold" in addition to "Myriad Pro Light", either manually for the entire machine or via the code for the QtApplication, there seems to be a name confusion between the two: Semibold is always used instead of light, and `<b>` tags cause a switch to bold tahoma.

So, long story short: how do I get QTextDocument to correctly set the fancy non-standard font of the text, based on the rich text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ugh. The issue was simply with the rich text.

Using this:

```
QString myRichText = "<span style="font-family:'Myriad Pro Light';">my text</span>
```

...worked much better.

Using this:

```
QString myRichText = "<span style="font-family:'Myriad Pro Light' font-weight=100;">my <b>text</b></span>
```

...also solved the name confusion between "light" and "semi-bold".

Thanks to all who looked into this.